# Bluez: cannot find Bluetooth device after failed pairing

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez

I am developing a simple app in python that uses bluez and dbus. The app should pair with a Bluetooth device - a raspberry Pi. I failed at pairing once, and now not only am I not able to reproduce the error, I can't even find the device anymore.

what I did:

- scanned for all the devices ( using the *startDiscovery()* function on an object implementing *org.bluez.Adapter1* interface)
- checked every found device if its MAC address matches the one I am looking for
- after finding the device I was looking for, I used its path to create a proxy object ( with *bus.get_object('org.bluez', device_path)* )
- I created *org.bluez.device1* interface on this object ( with *dbus.Interface(device_obj,                                               'org.bluez.Device1')* )
- I set the the "Trusted" property of this interface to True
- I called the *Pair()* function on this interface

This resulted in failed Pair attempt - it happened only once, I was not able to track down the error. Furthermore - the bluetooth on the raspberry Pi I tried to pair with stopped working: I was not able to advertise anymore. Rebooting and reinstalling bluez did not help, I had to reflash the SD card and install a fresh OS to make the bluetooth on RPi functional again.

On the application side I am able to scan and see all the other BT devices, except the one I failed to pair with. I tried rebooting, and reinstalling my code in the virtual environment.

If I run the *bluetoothctl scan on* program, I am able to see that RPi I am looking for. The *bluetoothctl paired-devices* list is empty. I belive the problem must be in my app.

I am really confused, and would be very grateful for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: I investigated the dbus, and just figured out that all the bluetooth devices I haven't tried pairing with use _org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager_ interface to manifest, however the one device I tried to pair with before uses the _org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties_ interface... Any idea why this happens? And why is it persistent after rebooting?